# toBreeze Spark function scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, breeze

I tried to understand the toBreeze function in Spark. And, I found the problem below:

```
<console>:37: error: method foreachActive in trait Vector cannot be accessed in org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
      vector.foreachActive{case (index,value) =>
```

dataSS is `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]`

```
dataSS.collect().foreach { vector =>
  vector.foreachActive { case (index,value) =>
    matData(i, index) = value
  }
  i +=1
}
```

Comment: can you explain more, post example input data?

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? As far as I know the `foreachActive` method on `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` has only become available in Spark 1.6. By the way, the `toBreeze` method (which you actually don't appear to be using) is private to Spark.

Comment: what is it you are doing ???

Answer (score 1):

I infer foreachActive must be private in the version of Spark you are using.

`foreachActive` is public and works fine for me in Spark 2.0.2

However `asBreeze` is private:

```
private[spark] override def asBreeze: BV[Double]
```

and when invoked generates the equivalent error to the one you see:

```
error: method asBreeze in trait Vector cannot be accessed in org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
```

(this is very annoying and not knowable from the [scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/Vector.html#asBreeze()) alone)